# What $context and $data refer to exactly in knockout?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the special properties $data and $context in knockout.js.

When changing the binding context with pager.js, I have to specify a `with: $context` to get my observable properties reachable and that doesn't sound normal to me.

Given that JS :

```
pager.useHTML5history = true;
pager.Href5.history = History;

var App = {};

App.user = {
  name: ko.observable('Me'),
  student: ko.observable(false)
};

App.user.setup = {
  setStudent: function() {
    App.user.student(true)
  }
};

pager.extendWithPage(App);

ko.applyBindings(App);
pager.startHistoryJs();
```

This HTML **works** :

```
<p><a href="#" data-bind="page-href: 'user/setup/role'">Role setup</a></p>
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'user', with: user, role: 'start'}" class="container">
  <div data-bind="page: {id: 'setup', with: setup}">
    <div data-bind="page: {id: 'role', with: $context}">
      <h2><strong data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>, are you a student ?</h2>
      <button data-bind="click: $context.setStudent">I am a student</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This HTML **doesn't work**, `setStudent` appears as undefined since I removed the `$context` preceding it :

```
<p><a href="#" data-bind="page-href: 'user/setup/role'">Role setup</a></p>
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'user', with: user, role: 'start'}" class="container">
  <div data-bind="page: {id: 'setup', with: setup}">
    <div data-bind="page: {id: 'role', with: $context}">
      <h2><strong data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>, are you a student ?</h2>
      <button data-bind="click: setStudent">I am a student</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this HTML **doesn't work**, no error pops out but the name remains blank :

```
<p><a href="#" data-bind="page-href: 'user/setup/role'">Role setup</a></p>
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'user', with: user, role: 'start'}" class="container">
  <div data-bind="page: {id: 'setup', with: setup}">
    <div data-bind="page: {id: 'role'}">
      <h2><strong data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>, are you a student ?</h2>
      <button data-bind="click: setStudent">I am a student</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, I know I am probably missing something in the concept of `$context`. I think it's refering to the entire ViewModel, including the data defined inside it. But apparently it's not.

Thanks !

Comment: this doc page will help: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: Sorry for not having mentioned that I've read this about twenty times, but still I can't figure out what exactly is the difference between $data and $context. If $data is supposed to represent the entire ViewModel, why do I have to speciy either one of $context or $data when binding to a specific context ? I don't have to do so in the $root context and can access both functions and properties.

Comment: I think your problem may be with how you are data-binding with what I assume is the pager.js plugin. I was able to get your example to work without using the paging and only using the 'with' binding. You don't need to use the 'with' binding on $context. Here is the fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/VNx34/](http://jsfiddle.net/VNx34/)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I finally managed to come to a good understanding of the binding context and understand how ridiculous is a `with: $context` binding. But still I'm wondering if this is not a bug with pager.js. I'm working on it, about to answer my own question.